# Vectorized version of df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've got a dataframe with a somewhat large amount of time series balances in it. It looks something like

```
      Run1    Run2    Run3    ...    Run10000
2018  100     100     100              100
2019 101.2   99.2    101.0    ...     101.6
...
2038 142.2   151.3   102.7    ...     173.0
```

Essentially I want to check to see how many trials ran dipped below a certain number, for example 90% of the starting balance.

Currently I am doing

```
((portfolio_values < starting_value*0.9).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).loc[True] > 0).value_counts().loc[True]
```

Sorry that one liner is pretty atrocious, but the idea is that it creates a mask based on whether a value in the table is below 90% of the starting value, then it goes through and does a count of True and False values. It then checks which of those columns has some non-zero number of True values (meaning yes, it did dip below 90%), then it counts up how many of those values are true.

The problem is that this is really slow, and I'm sure Pandas has some kind of function that does exactly what I'm looking for, as it normally does.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use:

```
(portfolio_values < starting_values*.9).any().sum()
```

`any` returns True for each column where the condition is met at least once in the column, then use sum to count the columns or "runs" in your case.

Comment: Answers like this make me feel dumb for asking, but yes that works exactly as I hoped. Thanks!

Comment: @Will pandas is a large library; it easy to not think of stuff.  You are welcome.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mask_df = df < starting_value*0.9
result = mask_df.any()
```

I tested it in a console on a dummy example and it appears to work.